# HTML5 CSS page is loading in the middle of the content, not desired

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have been working on an HTML5 page using CSS, and everything seems to be going well, but the page isn't loading at the top using Firefox 23.  When I loaded the page in Chrome it appeared to jump to the same spot that Firefox loaded, but then jumped the page to the top.

This is where the page seems to be loading on initial load using Firefox 23.

The page can be found on the internet, http://ipatch.github.io/KegCop/

**Update:** I just loaded the HTML page without the stylesheet and it appears it is still loading with the undesired behavior.

[image]

Comment: Can you post relevant code here.

Comment: It has the same behavior for me in Chrome

Comment: @putvande I'm not sure what part of the code is causing this load behavior :-/ Is the CSS or the HTML?

Comment: Try commenting out your script in the body and see how that behaves

Comment: @dc5 just tried that, and its still loading in the middle :-l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're experiencing this behavior because of the `autofocus` attribute you have set in your first input, it will (as the name suggests) add focus to it when the page loads

Comment: yeah i just commented out the contact form, and it seems the problem is somewhere in there.

Comment: It’s not “somewhere in there”. koala explicitly pointed to the issue.